# Command-Line File Content Search

Tags: windows-7

The Windows FIND and FINDSTR commands are ok for searching within certain types of files for matching string values, but neither of these works against newer MS-Office formats like DOCX, XLSX, or PPTX.  Is there another way to search within these files from a command line?  This would be on Windows Vista and Windows 7 computers only.

Answer (score -2):

Under Windows 7, you can add new file types to the index (Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced Options -> File Types). Don't forget to rebuild your index.

Some users also reported that they reinstalled MS Office 2007 and rebuild their index and after that content search of MS Office file types was OK.